# How the data is stored for the tables created via Web Sql database

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, web-sql

I am new to PhoneGap and am trying to create tables and insert data using WebSQL. 
On referring various questions regarding the path where it is stored, I found the path as given below:
/Users/XXXX/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/databases/
and the file available in this path is a binary path. I cannot find any other file in the same path. I am not sure if this is the file that i need. If so, how can i use this to be used in other systems.

Answer (score 1):

It's stored in a SQLite database. [Here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=sql-storage) is a browser support chart I found: .

That said, the W3C has officially dropped support for WebSQL in favor of IndexedDB. [Here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=indexeddb)'s the equivalent chart for that:

You may also want to look at [DataJS](http://datajs.codeplex.com/), which is a library that abstracts some of the details of local storage and works across browsers:

Hope that helps.